# How to have a pandas DATAFRAME saved into a SHAREPOINT as csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, sharepoint

I have a DataFrame that I would like to store as a CSV file in a Sharepoint.
It seems that the only way is to first save CSV file locally and then, using Shareplum, upload file to Sharepoint.
Is there a way to directly save DataFrame into Sharepoint as CSV file, without creating a local file?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to write the `csv` content to an in-memory text buffer (e.g. `StringIO` or `ByteIO`) rather than to a local file - [here is an example](https://pythontic.com/pandas/serialization/to_csv) (last section of the page).

After that, you could use a library for writing the content directly to a Sharepoint: [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696705/how-to-upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-site-using-python-script) shows several approaches how to do that, including the `Office365-REST-Python-Client` and also `SharePlum`, which you have already mentioned.

Here are two more sources (Microsoft technical doc) that you might find useful:

- [How can I upload a file to Sharepoint using Python?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/518566/how-can-i-upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-using-python.html)
- [How to get and upload files from sharepoint with python?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/612882/how-to-get-and-upload-files-from-sharepoint-with-p.html)