# Upload multiple worksheets as one workbook in SharePoint

Tags: python, sharepoint

I am hoping someone can help me please.

Below is the code I have to combine 3 dataframes and export it as an excel file locally to my own computer:

```
output = pd.ExcelWriter(r"FILEPATH")

headcount_raw.to_excel(output, sheet_name='Headcount_Raw')
YTD_Mobility.to_excel(output, sheet_name='YTD_Mobility')
Future_Mobility.to_excel(output, sheet_name='Future_Mobility')

output.save()
```

Now this works fine, but in order for me to scale out the Python RPA to the wider team I need to be able to run the code from files withinin SharePoint and rather than exporting it to my own computer I want to do the same as in extract all 3 dataframes in an excel file and save it in a location within a SharePoint folder.

I have tried the above code in the version for SharePoint but cant get it to work.

If someone has a use case similar to this I would appreciate your time to run me through the code you have or support me in this.

Thank you in advance!

KR

Koys

Comment: That's not RPA, it's a script. RPA is a term used for things that have no API, services or scripts that can be used to automate them, forcing people to try automating the application UI. SharePoint is a web site, not a local folder. It does have an PI though. You need to *upload* the generated Excel file to a SharePoint document library. [This possibly duplicate question shows how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696705/how-to-upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-site-using-python-script)

Comment: Thanks but your comments does not answer my question. Thank you for trying.