# Upload File to Windows Sharepoint using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, rest, sharepoint

I have a test.txt on my Desktop and now I want to upload it to a Sharepoint Directory via Python3. How can I do that?

Comment: what have you tried so far and where are you stuck please ?

Comment: I dont know how to do it so I cant try because Iam very new to programming.

Comment: The question has been asked before here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696705/how-to-upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-site-using-python-script   ... have you tried this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload a file to sharepoint site using python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696705/how-to-upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-site-using-python-script)

Comment: I have voted to close this question as it has been asked before and no attempt has been made.

Comment: I tried this but its not working for me. I dont have the knowledge to transfer this. I need more explanation. @D.L thank you for nothing. Do you never was a beginner in Programming? FY

Comment: I tried both of this and it didnt work and I dont know what happening there

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by saying this example is adapted from the example for Office365-REST-Python-Client. It works with sharepoint online using the rest api.

https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/files/upload_file.py

Example url you might want to upload to [baseurl][site][folder][file]. https://your_company.sharepoint.com/path/to/site/Shared Documents/file.txt

````
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

baseurl = 'https://your_company.sharepoint.com'
basesite = '/path/to/site' # every share point has a home.
siteurl = baseurl + basesite 

localpath = ./file.txt
remotepath = Shared Documents/file.txt # existing folder path under sharepoint site.

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password)
ctx = ClientContext(siteurl, ctx_auth) # make sure you auth to the siteurl.

with open(localpath, 'rb') as content_file:
    file_content = content_file.read()

dir, name = os.path.split(remotepath)
file = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(dir).upload_file(name, file_content).execute_query()```
````

Comment: Thank you but this didnt work. Becasue the module dont getting support